# Rails RSpec Testing: Undefined method 'deliver' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I"m trying to test whether a method triggers an email in my Rails 3.2 using RSpec.  It works in production and development, I just can't get it to pass my test.

I'm getting the error `undefined method 'deliver' for nil:NilClass`

```
# user_spec.rb
it "should send an email if user has weekly email set to true" do
  @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user, user_name: "Jane Doe", email: "jane@gmail.com", weekly_email: true, weekly_article_count: 10)
  Mailer.should_receive(:weekly_email)
  User.send_weekly_email
end

# user.rb
scope :weekly_email, where(:weekly_email => true)
scope :weekly_article_count, :conditions => ["weekly_article_count IS NOT NULL"]

def self.send_weekly_email
  @users = User.weekly_email.weekly_article_count
  @users.each do |user|
    Mailer.weekly_email(user).deliver
  end
end
```

I've also tried using `Mailer.should_receive(:weekly_email).with(user)`, but then I receive the error `undefined local variable or method 'user'`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Funny, I just had to do this a couple of hours ago.  You need to stub out the deliver method as well to stop it from freaking out.  Otherwise your `should_receive` returns nil so when your method calls `deliver` it's calling `nil.deliver`.

This should work:

```
Mailer.should_receive(:weekly_email).and_return( double("Mailer", :deliver => true) )
```

Answer (score 23):

Rspec has `and_call_original` if you don't need to change the original behavior. ([doc](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/message-expectations/calling-the-original-method))
In your case, you can use `Mailer.should_receive(:weekly_email).and_call_original`.

Comment: Here's the updated link to the doc: https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/configuring-responses/calling-the-original-implementation